# JSDoc : How to declare inline params

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I can't get jsdoc 3.5.5 to generate docs for inline comments.  Please see the attached example:

```
/**
 * my TestCase Class
 */
class TestCase {

    doesntWorkA(/** String */ str) /** Number */ {
        return 5;
    }

    doesntWorkB(/** @type {String} */ str) /** @type {Number} */ {
        return 5;
    }


    /**
    * @param {String} str
    * @return {Number}
    */
    works(str) {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: The language of their documentation for this ( http://usejsdoc.org/about-block-inline-tags.html ) implies that it's to be used in a description block: "Inline tags, which are within the text of a block tag or a description."

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that shows how to use it inline:

```
 hooks.run.tap('xxxx',/** @param {WebpackCompilation} compilation */ compilation => {
  ...
 });
```